# Binary search: Min value less than

Tags: c

The following C program searches an array for a value less than `search`. If values in "array" are positive integers, can I extrapolate this to any array length?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[11] = { 1, 5, 9, 15, 37, 49, 56, 65, 74, 90, 95};

    int first = 0;
    int last = 10;
    int search = 95;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;    
        else if (array[middle] > search)
            last = middle - 1;
        else break;

        printf("first= %d,last= %d, middle= %d, search= %d\n", first, last, middle, search);
        middle = (first + last)/2;
    }

    printf("middle =  %d\n",  array[middle]);
}
```

Thaks in advance,
Jose Luis

Comment: For example: if search=13, array[middle]=9; if search=59, array[middle]=56; if search=1, array[middle]=1; if search=130, array[middle]=95; ....

Comment: You want to say if you pass 95 to search, it will give second 90 in this case ?

Comment: No, if you pass 95 to search, it will give 95.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have **any array** length by setting required size in `array_size`, but you should input ordered number in the array.
Moreover you can also change `last` variable to a value, lower than `array_size - 1` e.g. in this case `8` but this will limit the search till `8` elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int array_size = 11;
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * array_size);

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        printf("%d \t", array[i]);
        printf("\n");

    int first = 0;
    int last = array_size - 1;
    int search = 7;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last)
    {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;  

        else if (array[middle] > search)
            last = middle - 1;

        else 
        {
            printf("%d found at indext %d\n", array[middle], middle);  
            return 0; 
        } 

        middle = (first + last)/2;
        printf("first= %d,last= %d, middle= %d, search= %d\n",
                first, last, middle, search);
    }

    printf("%d: Element not found\n", search);   
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @chux thanks for pointing out the bug. By saying "value lower than array_size" I meant actually lower than "array_size-1" :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 1 line in while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array[11] = { 1, 5, 9, 15, 37, 49, 56, 65, 74, 90, 95};

    int first = 0;
    int last = 11;
    int search = 95;
    int middle = (first+last)/2;

    while (first <= last) {
        middle = (first + last)/2; //this line
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] > search)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
        {
            printf("Found");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Not found");
    return 0;
}
```

You have to initialize middle when you change the first or last element. I have done it every time because this is the small program so it will not make big damage to performances.
When you don't do this, your middle element is staying before first element when you are searching and that is not what you want.